# Excel: Returning characters to the left and right of the last (or second to last) occurrence?

Tags: excel, string, return, formula

I have a string like this: 100 Stupid Street ; Government Tower 7; Chicago Palm, MA 92111

I want to return all the characters to the left of the last semicolon.

To the left of the last semicolon would be: 100 Stupid Street ; Government Tower 7

---

That was step 1. I would also like to extract characters from this string: Chicago Palm, MA 92111

I want to return all the characters to the right and left of the second to last space.

So,
To the right of the second to last space would be: MA 92111

To the left of the second to last space would be: Chicago Palm,

If there is a way to remove that last comma in that last formula, that would be even better.

---

This formula has helped me a bit:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

Cell A1 has the original string. This formula successfully returns everything to the right of the last semicolon.

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: With the variability in your middle section,it seems it would be a lot easier to do this in VBA with regular expressions, perhaps with a User Defined function.  That would also make it easier to account for variations that have not yet been demonstrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to parse out all of the pieces, some of the previous returns can assist in the next operation(s) so portions of formulas do not have to be repeated.

[image: stupid street]

B1 is `=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A3, ";", "×",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,";",""))), FIND("×",SUBSTITUTE(A3&"×", ";", "×",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,";",""))))-1)`

B2 is `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

B3 is `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A3,",",REPT(" ",99)),99))`

B4 is `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A4,B3,""),",",""))`

Comment: Thank you, both answers work. However, using the same formulas on this string yields not intended results:                              300 Test Lane; Tower ABC; Room 6; Boston MA 02311 (notice it doesn't have the comma)

Comment: @Yogs777 - I think that enough examples have been provided that you should be able to start trying your own formulas. Post back with examples of your own effort(s) and we will try to help if things do not work out.

Comment: Slight discrepancy solved with a few simple formulas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version:

```
B1      =LEFT(A1,(FIND(";",A1,FIND(";",A1)+1))-1)               ==> 100 Stupid Street ; Government Tower 7
B2      =TRIM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(";",A1,FIND(";",A1)+1)))    ==> Chicago Palm, MA 92111
B3      =LEFT(B2,FIND(",",B2)-1)                                ==> Chicago Palm
B4      =TRIM(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-(FIND(",",B2)+1)))               ==> MA 92111
```

More generic:

```
B1   =LEFT(A1,(FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","^",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","")))))-1)
```

And performing substitutions can be achieved otherwise. Homework.

Comment: Using the same formula on this string gives the wrong answer. Is there a way to make your good formulas more generic to this variation?                                                String: 300 Test Lane; Tower ABC; Room 6; Boston MA 02311